# Class method uses an array not passed

Tags: python, class, global-variables, pass-by-reference

So, I'm tring to program a variant of the knapsack problem but I'm really new to the use of Python and I stumbled on this.

I'm using Jupyter (Python 3)

```
class Gene(object):
    def __init__(self, weight, price):
        self.weight = weight
        self.price = price

obj1 = Gene(10, 20)
obj2 = Gene(25, 5)
obj3 = Gene(5, 10)

genes = [obj1, obj2, obj3]

class Chromosomes(object):

    def __init__(self, flagIndex_of_items_contained = []):
        self.flagIndex_of_items_contained = flagIndex_of_items_contained
        self.myWeight = self.Define_myWeight()

    def Define_myWeight(self):
        weight = 0
        for index_flag in range(len(self.flagIndex_of_items_contained)):
            if(self.flagIndex_of_items_contained[index_flag] == 1):
                weight = weight + genes[index_flag].weight
        return weight

chromosome1 = Chromosomes([1,0,1])

print("chromosome1 weight: ", chromosome1.myWeight)
```

Output

chromosome1 weight:  15

BUT

**genes[index_flag].weight**

How can this command work if i don't pass the array genes to the class?

Comment: Because `genes` has a bigger scope than the class

Comment: This is, IMO, badly written code. It's accessing a global variable and also has a mutable default argument. It's also not a general way to solve a combinatorial problem.

Comment: here's a good [article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword) on pythons global variable scope. It should explain why your code is working and what the general rules about the scope is used for.

Comment: @roganjosh "badly written code". I'm new, you're not helpful. What do you mean, I prefer answer with examples ty.
And yeah that's not all the code obviously...

Comment: I explained why i thought it wasn't good code immediately after that statement. It's tangential to what you were asking but you are free to pick up on terms like "mutable default argument" and search for them. Would it be _more_ helpful if I didn't draw attention to bad practice and didn't post?

Comment: I'm called grumpy and unhelpful all the time here @roganjosh, even I can see that that comment might not be helpful to new programmers or even to experienced ones. You're just pointing out that something is bad and why you think it's bad. Not what would be a better approach. Think of including that in your next sentence stating why something is bad. For instance, "A better approach would be to <insert good idea here>". You should point out bad code, but point in a direction that someone can understand and use.

Comment: Ty all... I'm just new to Python

Comment: @Torxed I understand what you're saying and I would hope that you would see that I do try to explain in my comments and answers what's going on. The point here was not to try go into all the details of how it isn't good code but more to explain that I don't think it's good material to be working from (The OP just found it). Indeed I couldn't in a comment, nor would an answer be appropriate to address side concerns. Being told to "answer better" was a nice touch from the OP, though.

Comment: That comment is gone now, though and I hope by the OP's choice not forced. I certainly didn't flag it.

Comment: @roganjosh I've seen a lot of your comments and answers (you've even commented on some of my questions), so I know you only mean well and you usually keep a neutral standpoint and tone. And you come with good insights, so I know you try to explain. Sorry if my pointer sounded harsh. I come in peace! :)

Comment: @Torxed not at all, I also know you and your intentions (from SO at least) and I take your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable `genes` lives on the same level as the classes, the module level. In the problematic line

```
weight = weight + genes[index_flag].weight
```

the interpreter simply sees that there is no local variable with the scope of the function `Define_myWeight`, hence it checks the global scope (module level). On this level `genes` exists and the interpreter can use it.

Besides that, issues because of which your code has been considered "badly written".

1. Use global variables only if they are absolutely necessary. Check some arbitrary tutorial on globals to understand this proposition.
2. You should never use a mutable object as default parameter. Lists are mutable objects in Python, that means they can be changed. Use immutable objects, like tuples, in such cases.

   ```
   def func1(some_arg = []):    # bad
   def func1(some_arg = ()):    # ok
   ```
3. Do not mix different format styles. Use either `CamelCase` or `names_with_underscores`. Check out the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for that.

Here is an idea to improve your code. Chromosomes are made up of different genes. The following code models this relation.

```
class Gene:
    def __init__(self, weight, price):
        self.weight = weight
        self.price = price


class Chromosom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.genes = []
        self.flag_idx = []
        self.weight = 0

    def add_gene(self, weight, price):
        self.genes.append(Gene(weight, price))

    def compute_weight(self, flags):
        for i, flag in enumerate(flags):
            if flag == 1:
                self.weight += self.genes[i].weight
```

Usage:

```
ch = Chromosom()

ch.add_gene(10, 20)
ch.add_gene(25, 5)
ch.add_gene(5, 10)

ch.compute_weight((1, 0, 1))

print(ch.weight)
```